# Can you solve $\int \frac{1}{2x+1} dx $ without substitution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Is it possible to solve the integral
$$\int \frac{1}{2x+1} dx $$
without substitution?

I can solve it with substitution, so don't worry. I just want to know if there is some nice trick without substitution.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2dx}{2x+1}=\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+1|+C$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2x+1} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}}$ is the derivative of $\log\left|x+\frac{1}{2}\right|$.

Comment: If you consider reversing the chain-rule so you need to multiply the result by $\frac{1}{2}$ to "cancel" the $2$ produced by the chain rule and get $\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+1| + c$. This is, however, just a perspective change on what u-substitution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wish to avoid simple substitution or any semblance thereof, we can write

$$\frac{1}{2x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2x)^n$$

for $|x|< 1/2$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{2x+1}\,dx&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2x)^{n}}{n}+C\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log(1+2x)+C
\end{align}$$

---

If $|x|>1/2$, then we can write

$$\frac{1}{2x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(2x)^{-(n+1)}=\frac1{2x}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n(2x)^{-(n+1)}$$

and we have

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{2x+1}\,dx&=\frac12\log(|x|)+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2x)^{-n}}{n}+C\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log(|x|)+\log\left(1+\frac1{2x}\right)\right)+C\\\\
&=\frac12\log(|1+2x|)+C'
\end{align}$$

Putting it all together, we have that

$$\int \frac1{2x+1}\,dx=\frac12\log(|1+2x|)+C$$

for all $x\ne -1/2$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was what I searched for.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 6):

Substitution is just a way to notice that something is the derivative of something else. In this case, with a bit of experience, one sees easily that $$\int \frac{1}{2x+1} dx=\frac12\,\log|2x+1|+C.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was looking more for a series approach.

Answer (score 4):

No substitution required, just some geometric series:

$$\begin{align}\int\frac1{1+2x}\ dx&=\int1-2x+(2x)^2-(2x)^3+\dots\ dx\tag{$|x|<\frac12$}\\&=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^nx^n\ dx\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^n\int x^n\ dx\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\end{align}$$

Though probably not what you wanted?  If you knew the geometric series to the natural logarithm, though, you'd see that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(2x)^n}n=\frac12\ln(1+2x)$$

which holds by analytic continuation for $x\in\mathbb R$.

If you prefer, for $|x|>\frac12$, one could instead use

$$\frac1{1+2x}=\frac{\frac1{2x}}{1+\frac1{2x}}$$

and then applying the geometric series as Dr.MV has shown.

Comment: @Downvoter: I don't see what's wrong with this answer. Consider explaining why the downvote.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is nice to see another approach. This was the stuff I was looking for.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this isn't complete inasmuch as the series you wrote is not valid for $|x|>1/2$.  I've posted a solution that accounts for this. ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV :P That is true, nice catch.

Comment: @WaldoRozir No problem :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You might consider, at a minimum, stating the region of convergence in the solution.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Yup and thanks for pointing that out.